# Iron-router asynchronus template choosing

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, iron-router

I want iron-router to choose the template based on a current time. For security reasons i can't trust the client time. So i wrote Meteor method what can return the server time. But Meteor.call can't return some value synchronously, so i need to provide some callback. It's not a problem, but i can't find any way to force router wait until callback get data. I tried to use route.render('template') in callback and it's work, but with delay  (as expected). At first i see the template with route-data, and after moment it's replaced by restricted_template. So how i can choose the template base on data what returned from Meteor.call()? Or maybe exists some another way to get server time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sync the time, then in the callback run `Router.go('someRoute');`.

Haven't looked at it much, but there are several packages for getting server time on the client.  One such package `https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync`

But be aware that if you're routes are all that are keeping your application secure, it isn't secure.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand. What does mean 'sync the time'? I just need to get time from server. User can set any time he want: +day, +week, +year or more..